# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text' python 2.7

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, nonetype

So I'm trying to read a `div` from a web page that has content that I want to extract. Been learning Beautiful Soup to extract this info, but when I attempt to extract it, it doesn't get any of the info.

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


openUrl = urllib2.urlopen("https://www.metal-archives.com/lists/AF")
findCount = BeautifulSoup(openUrl, "html.parser")
divStuff = findCount.find("div",{"class":"dataTables_info"})

print divStuff.get_text(strip=True)
```

I have also tried `divStuff.text`, `findAll`, using the `id` instead, but none of those seem to work.

This is the `div` that I'm trying to extract from. I know that there's stuff that I could take. So I'm not sure why it can't read it.

[image]

Comment: The problem is that you can't read stuff from that div, it's that you can't find the div in the first place. That error message means that `divStuff` is `None`, rather than div element, and `None` obviously doesn't have a `get_text` method. So, you're trying to debug the wrong line.

Comment: And meanwhile, when I download that page in Python, there is no div with that class. The closest thing is `dataTables_wrapper`. So, most likely, either (1) you're looking at al old version of the page to try to parse the current version, or (2) the div you're looking for isn't on the page, it's added on the fly by JavaScript (in which case you need to use something like Selenium or PhantomJS, so you can actually run that JavaScript and access the results of doing so).

Comment: Yeah, I don't see the `dataTables_info` either. I can try to ask the owner of the website to see what they've done.

Comment: If you can get help from the owner of the site, there may be a much better answer: the JavaScript that generates the page is probably making calls to some API. If they give you permission to use that API, and some basic documentation, you don't need to screen-scrape the HTML at all, just make API calls. That'll be easier on you, and less load on their server, too.

Comment: Actually, from a quick glance, it looks like [they already have a public API](http://em.wemakesites.net/). So you should probably just use that.

Comment: Huh, guess I'll check that out.